# Xtext list of items or only one item

Tags: grammar, xtext

I'm trying to create a grammar that would parse the following:

```
reference: java.util.String
```

but as well

```
reference: {java.util.String, java.lang.Integer}
```

In other words, I want it to parse both a list of Qualified names but also only one item (not marked by '{' in this case).

What I tried is this:

```
Reference:
    'reference' ':' ('{' values+=QualifiedName (',' values+=QualifiedName)* '}') | (values+=QualifiedName);
```

However, I am getting an error: missing '{' at 'java', when using the first form of the reference (without {). Any suggestions what I should try?

EDIT: Also tried

```
Reference:
    'reference' ':' ('{' values+=QualifiedName (',' values+=QualifiedName)* '}') | ((!'{')values+=QualifiedName);
```

but getting a no viable alternative at input '!' error in the grammar definition.

EDIT2: I am not having problems with the "comma separated list", I tried this separatly and it works well. My only problem is distinguishing between the two parts of the rule based on the '{' character.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This will do the trick:

```
Reference:
'reference' ':' (
     '{' values+=QualifiedName (',' values+=QualifiedName)* '}' 
   | values+=QualifiedName
);
```

Please mind the precedencies of groups and alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

I am quite new to Xtext, so just giving it a try:

```
Reference:
    'reference' ':' ('{' values+=QualifiedName (',' values+=QualifiedName)* '}') | (values=QualifiedName);
```

or

```
Reference:
    'reference' ':' ('{' values+=QualifiedName (',' values+=QualifiedName)+ '}') | (values=QualifiedName);
```

Comment: First: Can't assign QualifiedName to values since it has a different cardinality to the other case of values (getting an error in the grammar). Second: I need the list to be of undefined size so + won't fit (means 0 or 1).  Thanks for the try though.